# Slack incoming webhook vs postMessage Web API

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

What is the difference between [incoming webhook](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) and slack [chat.postMessage webAPI](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)?

When should we use one over another? I have a slack app, I want to send messages to particular channel as a User. I found an option to post message as a User in chat.postMessage, can I achieve this by incoming webhook?

Answer (score 4):

To your specific question. Its technically possible to send messages on behalf of a user with `chat.postMessage` by using a token from that user and setting `as_user` to `true`.

For example if you installed a Slack app the created app token will be linked to the installing user and you can use it send messages on behalf of the installing user.